# Unable to change a custom workflow environment variable in a job step

Tags: macos, github-actions

I set an environment variable for my workspace like so :

```
env:
  DATA_BRANCH: master
```

and then I would like to change it in one of the job steps (for macos)

`echo {DATA_BRANCH=osx} >> $GITHUB_ENV`

but this does not change the variable.

My complete yml file is:

https://github.com/GrokImageCompression/grok/blob/master/.github/workflows/build.yml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was a syntax error

`echo DATA_BRANCH=osx >> $GITHUB_ENV` is the proper syntax - no curly braces required.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [official documentation](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/environment-variables):

> The scope of a custom environment variable is limited to the element in which it is defined.

Which means that if you set a env variable at the workflow level, at the job level, or at the step level. **The most specific one will always prevails**.

In your case, you set at the workflow level:

```yaml
env:
  DATA_BRANCH: master
```

If you want a specific step (or job) to use another value, you just need to set the env variable at that level with the other value.

In your case, it would look like this:

```yaml
  steps:
    ...
    - name: macos-dependencies
      if: startsWith(matrix.os, 'macos')
      run: |
        ...
      env:
        DATA_BRANCH: osx
```

It's also worth remembering that using `echo name=value >> $GITHUB_ENV` won't add the env variable to the current step, but only to the following ones ([reference](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-commands-for-github-actions#setting-an-environment-variable)):

> The step that creates or updates the environment variable does not have access to the new value, but all subsequent steps in a job will have access.

Comment: Thanks. what I want to do is to set a default value for DATA_BRANCH at workflow level, then customise it for macos, and then use the value in a subsequent step. So, master is the default value, but on macos it gets changed.  My problem is that setting the value using $GITHUB_ENV does not change it for following steps.

Comment: Understood. I use to set env variable in separated step to segregate responsabilities. Too much operations ocurring in the same step may be confusing sometimes. It's good you found the problem 